# Having trouble drawing BufferedImage of type TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE with Graphics2D

Tags: java, image, graphics2d, lottie

In my program I am given image data in pre-multiplied ARGB format.  I'm doing the following to create a BufferedImage, paint it to a canvas, and then render it to a PNG image but the resulting image has the wrong colors:

```
    IntBuffer imageData = ....;
    BufferedImage renderedFrame = createBufferedImage(surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight(), imageData);
    DataBufferInt rasterData = (DataBufferInt)renderedFrame.getData().getDataBuffer();
    imageData.get(rasterData.getData());
    ImageIO.write(renderedFrame, "PNG", new File("/tmp/renderedFrame.png")); // the image is rendered, but the colors are all off

    final BufferedImage canvasImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
    final Graphics2D g = canvasImage.createGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, surface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight());
    g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
    g.drawImage(renderedFrame, 0, 0, width, height, null, null);
    ImageIO.write(canvasImage, "PNG", new File("/tmp/canvasImage.png")); // the image is rendered, but the colors are all off
```

I have verified that the image data is correct, It's coming from rlottie (https://github.com/Samsung/rlottie).  I just need to composite it onto another image.

For the first `createBufferedImage` method I'm using `DirectDataBufferInt` from the jogl library: https://github.com/JogAmp/jogl/blob/master/src/nativewindow/classes/com/jogamp/nativewindow/awt/DirectDataBufferInt.java so that the image's DataBuffer is backed by the NIO buffer.  Here's the content of the `createBufferedImage` method:

```
private BufferedImage createBufferedImage(int width, int height, ByteBuffer buffer) {
    DirectDataBufferInt intBuffer = new DirectDataBufferInt(buffer, width * height);
    return DirectDataBufferInt.createBufferedImage(width, height, intBuffer, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE, null, null);
}
```

Here's a render of the source image on a white background:

[image: sampleImageRenderedElsewhere.jpg]

Here's the rendered frame (`renderedFrame.png`):

[image: renderedFrame.png]

And here's what it looks like when i render it with the above code (`canvasImage.png`):

[image: canvasImage.png]

They look the same but they are not. `canvasImage.png` has a white background while `renderedFrame.png` is transparent.

Comment: this is not your normal drawImage() ok? g.drawImage(renderedFrame, 0, 0, width, height, null, null); second: if your background is just white what are you decomposing??

Comment: This TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE thing I dont know what it is for; Use a normal ARGB!!!

Comment: This is a normal draw image.  TYPE_INT_ARGB_PRE is an ARGB format where the colors are pre-multiplied with the alpha.  This is a common technique for improving performance (avoiding additional math calculations when drawing) and unfortunately I do not get to choose the pixel format... i must use ARGB_PRE

Comment: In your code, you write the image twice. Is the output you attach `renderedFrame.png` or `canvasImage.png` (or do they look the same)? The image attached is also a JPEG, but your image stores PNG... Not sure if that's imgur, but it would be interesting to see the exact PNG output.

Comment: Possibly a BGRA (or similar) -> ARGB issue? What does the code in `createBufferedImage` look like? The problem may be there.

Comment: @haraldK - i'll attach an image for the first one.

Answer (score 1):

So this is my bad. Since I never verified the incoming format I ended up sending myself on a goose chase.  Essentially the rlottie docs say `ARGB32_Premultiplied` format.  But the bytes are stored (in order of appearance): BGRA.  So I was basically mixing up my channels.  I guess because they use a uint32 for the buffer I should have realized that?  Anyway - problem solved.  Thanks everyone for the help.